# How can change pom.xml property when creating new project from local archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I am trying to create arhetype from my own maven project. I have some properties at pom.xml as;

```
<properties>
    <path.property>${path}</path.property>
</properties>
```

This property is used at my project from command line. I wanna create archetype and use this property at when generation of new project from this archetype. So new project's pom.xml property value of `path.property` will be variable which is entered.

For example when i entered -Dpath=/src/main/java while new project generation with my archetype, i want to have like this pom.xml ;

```
<properties>
    <path.property>${path}</path.property>
</properties>
```

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your custom property `path` in the archetype-metadata.xml. If you define the property as required, then the property will be prompted when you use the archetype from command line.

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/archetype-descriptor.html